# WCF, multiple async calls

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I have a View in Windows Form that needs to execute multiple WCF calls async.
The problem is that when the second callback return, WCF raises an error of timeout or a generic exception. If I execute them sync everything is fine.
This is the code:

```
Proxy.Open();
Proxy.BeginStepOne(ar => 
{
   // do something
});    

//This raises an Exception
Proxy.BeginStepTwo(ar => 
{
   // do something
});
Proxy.Close();
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm going on the _belief_ that you're `Proxy.Close` is being called before the call-back to your delegate. Try changing the location of the close so it happens after your last call.

Comment: Ok, I am trying that right now.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the second one bombs saying: 
Async End called on wrong channel.
Parameter name: result

Comment: If I open a channel for each call it works fine, otherwise at the second one it bombs

Comment: Putting the close in one of the delegates isn't the answer (assuming you're trying that). You need a way of synching that all call-backs have returned before you attempt to close the connection. (I assume this is in Silverlight?) Maybe use a counter variable set to the number of call-backs your anticipating, then for every return (erroneous or successful) decrement the counter. When it reaches 0, then close the Proxy.

Comment: Nope, it is a windows form application that needs to execute 4 parallel steps.